# How to make do while loop after validating email address?

Tags: java, do-while

```
// My Scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   
//using Do While Loop
do {
    //Asking user to enter email
    System.out.println("enter your email:");
    //Read and safe input in to Var userEmail
    String userEmail = input.next();
    //Check for contains '@' and '.com' simbols
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+?@\\S+?\\.com");
    //And it checking in users entered email
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(userEmail);
    //if userEmail contain '@'and '.com' print next line
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Matches"); // Prints this for this email    
    }
    //if user put email with out '@'and'.com' print next line
    else {
        System.out.println("your email should 
        looks like this sample bob.Dillon@gmail.com");
    }
// And here I have a problem don't know what to type in
// so that it starts looping until user input will be 100% correct.
} while(!matcher.matches());
```

Can someone help what needs to be done here `while(here);` to make it looping?

Comment: So, uh, what do you mean by all those 'Blockquote's?

Comment: Sorry about that just clicked them by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to see if the user entered anything in those fields. So, check like this:

```
if (INPUTVALUE.length > 0) { //THEY ENTERED SOMETHING
    // do something
}
```

Then, put this in your `while` statement. Like so:

```
// My Scanner
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   
    //using Do While Loop
    do{
        //Asking user to enter email
        System.out.println("enter your email:");
        //Read and safe input in to Var userEmail
        String userEmail = input.next();
        //Check for contains '@' and '.com' simbols
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+?@\\S+?\\.com");
        //And it checking in users entered email
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(userEmail);
        //if userEmail contain '@'and '.com' print next line
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Matches"); // Prints this for this email    
        }
        //if user put email with out '@'and'.com' print next line
        else{
            System.out.println("your email should 
            looks like this sample bob.Dillon@gmail.com");
        }
    //And here I have a problem don't know what to type in so that it starts looping until user input will be 100% correct 
    }while(INPUTVALUE.length > 0);
```

**You need:**

```
}while(INPUTVALUE.length > 0);
```

**To break the loop**:

Just erase all of the values that the user has entered at the end of the **do**. That way, INPUTVALUE.length < 0. That will break the loop ! Good luck !

Comment: Any idea how to stop this loop :)

Comment: @KonstantinF just erase all of the values that the user has entered at the end of the **do** that way, INPUTVALUE.length < 0. That breaks the loop ! Good luck !